# Is it possible to define a Tcl procedure in Python?

Tags: python, menu, tcl, tk-toolkit

According to this [tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html#platformmenus), you need to define a Tcl procedure named `::tk::mac::ShowPreferences` to make the preferences... option on the applications menu active.  Is it possible to do this in Python?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it is possible, at least IDLE does so. Its [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/idlelib/macosxSupport.py#l136) contains the line:

```
root.createcommand('::tk::mac::ShowPreferences', config_dialog)
```

If you google for `createcommand` you will find other related OSX examples.

Comment: I was just about to post this, hah.

Comment: So simple... I must have tried ten variations but not the obvious one.  I forgot about IDLE, lots of good stuff in idlelib.